# How to add/remove workers programatically in celery?

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

So basically, I want to manage the workers based on the queue size/time of the day for one particular queue. I want to run less number of workers for a queue in peak hours and increase them when the load comes down.

Answer (score 1):

You can check out the documentation for `celery.worker.autoscale`. This allows you to set the minimum and maximum concurrency, and Celery will handle the pool of workers. Not 100% sure how it works to be honest but seems like a good starting point.

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/internals/reference/celery.worker.autoscale.html